# Samsung Gear S: Continuous Heart Rate Monitoring

Tags: android, heartbeat, samsung-mobile-sdk

I'm trying to develop an app that reasons on heart rate data. I have a Samsung Gear S and I would like to get a continuous heart rate stream from the watch
to my app on my phone. I did a lot of research about this but didn't find
what I was looking for. Therefore I've got some questions.

What I learned is that the Gear S only measures your heart rate when you are working out. So in order to get continuous heart monitoring, you should start a workout. Should I therefore write my own app on the Gear S that measures your heart rate? And if so, is this possible with the Standalone or Companion type SDK (http://developer.samsung.com/gear)?

I've also read that you can use the remote sensor SDK (http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy#remote-sensor) but that it only allows to 
get the user activity, pedometer data and the state whether the user wears wearable device. Can you also get the heart rate?

Basically what I would like to know is whether this is possible and if so
which steps I should take?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question on the developer forum of Samsung and I found an anwser.

> You should write your own wearable app to measure continous heart rate, and the app need to communicate with Android host app via SAP(Samsung Accessory Protocol) so that your Andorid  host app to be able to get coutinous heart rate data from a wearable device. So the app type should be companion type.
>
> Remote sensor SDK does not support HRM.